# How can I distinguish different consonants in Praat/acoustic analysis?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, consonants, acoustic-analysis

How can I distinguish different consonants based on acoustic information/spectrographic analysis such as in [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/)? Is there a list of acoustic cues for different consonants like there is for [average vowel formants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant#Formants%20and%20phonetics)?

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics SE! For others to be able to answer your questions you might need to expand your question a little. What exactly do you want to do? Determine boundaries between consonants and vowels? Determine what consonant was produced at a certain part of a recording? Also, what do you already know? Have you consulted any textbooks on Acoustic phonetics?

Comment: Determine what consonant was produced at a certain part of a recording? - yes, exactly. Sorry for non informative question. I have a little trouble with posting my question. I have read wikipedia on vowels and consonants and help of praat. I already now that the vowels might be distiguished by the formants F1, F2 and F3. And its not the case of consonants. So how we can distinguish them if we dont have precise F1, F2...

Comment: It's a little more difficult than with vowels. Manner of articulation is easy in consonants, but place of articulation is tricky. If you have at least some previous knowledge in acoustic phonetics try the relevant chapters in [Hayward's *Experimental Phonetics*](http://www.amazon.com/Experimental-Phonetics-Introduction-Katrina-Hayward/dp/0582291372/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1377268235&sr=8-1&keywords=experimental+phonetics).

Comment: I know about VOT, but i'm not sure if we can consider VOT as a main characteristics of consonant. And i don't find table with example of VOT for each consonant as we have for vowels in wikipedia.

Comment: Do you have a specific task to accomplish? Like transcribing a recording? Then spectrographic analysis should only complement an auditory analysis. Or are you asking for general knowledge?

Comment: VOT is only useful for determining voicing and it's language-dependent.

Comment: This is what you usually study in an Acoustic Phonetics class. I'd recommend Chapter 8 in Ladefoged's A Course in Phonetics, esp. Table 8.1 Acoustic correlates of consonantal features. After that you could take a look at something more detailed, like Olive, Greenwood and Coleman, Acoustics of American English Speech, or Johnson's Acoustic and Auditory Phonetics.

Comment: The standard textbook is Stevens' Acoustic Phonetics.

Comment: @Alex B. Thank you. _Table 8.1 Acoustic correlates of consonantal features_ — that's what I was looking for.

Comment: I would be interested in the answer to this too, to help determine an unclear stop consonant in a recording.